# What does it mean for a complex valued function on $G(\mathbb A)$ to be smooth (or smooth of compact support)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, langlands-conjectures, reductive-groups, adeles

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a number field $k$.  Let $\mathbb A$ denote the adeles of $k$, $\mathbb A_f$ the finite adeles, and $k_{\infty} = \prod\limits_{v \mid \infty} k_v$.  Here are two equivalent definitions for a function $\phi: G(\mathbb A) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ to be "smooth."

> - $\phi$ is smooth if, writing $G(\mathbb A) = G(k_{\infty}) \times G(\mathbb A_f)$, $\phi$ is smooth (infinitely differentiable) in the first variable and smooth (locally constant) in the second variable.  I saw this definition [here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/%7Ematgwt/china3.pdf).
> - $\phi$ is smooth if for every $g \in G(\mathbb A)$, there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $g$ and a smooth (infinitely differentiable) function $\phi_g: G(k_{\infty}) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ such that for all $h = (h_{\infty}, h_f) \in V \subset G(\mathbb A) = G(k_{\infty}) \times G(\mathbb A_f)$, we have $\phi(h) = \phi_g(h_{\infty})$.  I saw this definition in Daniel Bump's book, *Automorphic Forms and Representations*, page 299.

Choose an embedding $G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n$, so we can talk about $G(\mathcal O_v) := G(k_v) \cap \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathcal O_v)$.  Denote the space of smooth functions on $G(\mathbb A)$ by $C^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$.  Let $C_c^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$ be the space of $\phi \in C^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$ which vanish outside of a compact set in $G(\mathbb A)$.  There is another definition of $C_c^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$ which I have seen before (see my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168413/definition-of-the-l-function-lf-chi-s-mathbba-k-rightarrow-mathbbc)).  Namely:

> - $C_c^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$ is defined to be the space of finite linear combinations of "factorizable" functions $\prod_v f_v$ for $f_v: G(k_v) \rightarrow \mathbb C$ smooth (infinitely differentiable or locally constant, depending on whether $v$ is infinite or finite), where $f_v = \operatorname{Char} G(\mathcal O_v)$ for almost all places $v$.

My second question is: are these two definitions of $C_c^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$ the same?  The first one defines it as a subspace of $C^{\infty}(G(\mathbb A))$, and the second defines it intrinsically as combinations of factorizable functions.

Comment: I haven't thought this through thoroughly but I think the answer is yes. The idea is that the full Hecke algebra of a restricted direct product of locally compact totally disconnected groups is the tensor product of the local Hecke algebras.

Comment: Restricted tensor product of the local Hecke algebras, I mean.

Comment: Being able to speak of $G(\mathscr O_v)$ is a matter of choosing an $\mathscr O_v$-structure on $G$, not an embedding $G \to \mathrm{GL}_n$.  (Think, for example, of how you genuinely need a real structure, not just a (complex) embedding on a general linear group, on a complex group $G$ before you can speak of $G(\mathbb R)$.)

Comment: Also, although it's just a wording issue, it's not clear to me what makes the second definition intrinsic and the first one not.

Comment: @LSpice I know, but I think at almost all places $G(\mathcal O_v)$ as I defined it will be the $\mathcal O_v$ points of a nice $\mathcal O_v$-structure, right?

Comment: My point was that you *haven't* defined it; an embedding $G \to \mathrm{GL}_n$ doesn't allow one to speak of $G(\mathscr O_v)$, at least not in an algebro-geometric way.  Did you mean simply to define $G(\mathscr O_v) \mathbin{:=} G(k_v) \cap \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathscr O_v)$?  That's a definition one can make, but I suspect that it can go wrong for a random choice of embedding.

Comment: Yes, I defined $G(\mathcal O_v)$ that way.  I don't mean to say it's a group scheme.  I thought I remembered that if $G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}_n$ is a $k$-embedding then at almost all places, $G(\mathcal O_v)$ as I defined it will work as it should.

Comment: @D_S The point is to fix a scheme $GL_n \rightarrow Spec(\mathcal{O})$ and then use the embedding to define the structure of $G$ as a scheme over $\mathcal{O}$. You need both to refer to $G(\mathcal{O})$.

Comment: Yes.  Your two definitions of $C^\infty(G({\mathbb A}))$ are equivalent, and with a compact support condition, equivalent to the third.  The exercise is to prove that, given a closed embedding of $k$-groups from $G$ to $GL_n$, the subspace topology on $G({\mathbb A})$ from $GL_n({\mathbb A})$ coincides with the restricted direct product topology, with respect to the open compact subgroups $G(K_v) \cap GL_n(O_v)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  So it is true that almost all of the $f_v$ are the characteristic function of $G(\mathcal O_v) := G(k_v) \cap \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathcal O_v)$, even though $G(\mathcal O_v)$ is not necessarily coming from a group scheme?

Comment: @D_S:  Yes -- it's fine at almost all places, as long as the one embeds $G$ as a closed subgroup of $GL_n$ over the base field $k$.